# Make function private for another workbook in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

First of all, sorry about my English. I'm still learning....
I wanna know how can I make some function or modulus inaccessible for another workbook. In contrast I need these function public for all modulus inside workbook. I make myself clear?
For example:
I need to open two workbook that contains function with the same name but these functions perform things a little bit different.

Comment: How are you calling these functions? By default, functions are not directly accessible between workbooks unless you use `Application.Run` or call them from a cell and explicitly include the workbook name.

Comment: Ohh ok... Now I understand well... I thought that function could be called for all workbooks without any specifc code.

Answer (score 1):

See here for an answer http://www.cpearson.com/excel/scope.aspx

Here's a copied summary:

If you want a variable to be accessible from anywhere within the project, but not accessible from another project, you need to use Option Private Module as the first line in the module (above and outside of any variable declaration or procedure). This option makes everything in the module accessible only from within the project. This means also that if you do want some project variables to be accessible from other projects and other project variables to be inaccessible from other projects, you need to declare them in separate modules.